# PHP Socket SMTP Handshake VRFY email

Tags: php, sockets, smtp, handshake

How to verify email address is valid/invalid using SMTP handshake? My code always shows invalid email does not exist. But actually it's exists.

In this code I'm using SMTP details to verify recipient email is valid/invalid.

```
$smtpHost = 'mail.sender.com'; // Replace with your SMTP server hostname
            $smtpPort = 587; // Use the appropriate port for your SMTP server
            $localDomain = 'sender.com'; // Replace with the name of your server
            $recipientEmail = 'noreply@receiver.com'; // Replace with the recipient's email
            $username = 'noreply@sender.com';
            $password = '**********';
            list(,$domain) = explode("@",$recipientEmail);

            // Open a socket connection to the SMTP server
            $socket = fsockopen($smtpHost, $smtpPort, $errno, $errstr, 30);
            
            if (!$socket) {
                echo "Failed to open socket: $errstr ($errno)";
            } else {
                
                function readResponse($socket) {
                    $response = '';
                    do {
                        $line = fgets($socket, 512);
                        $response .= $line;
                    } while (preg_match('/^\d{3}-/', $line));
            
                    echo $response;
                    return $response;
                }
            
                // Read the initial response from the server
                $response = readResponse($socket);
            
                // Send the EHLO (or HELO) command to the SMTP server
                fputs($socket, "EHLO $localDomain\r\n"); // Use EHLO or HELO as needed
                $response = readResponse($socket);
            
                // Check if the server responds with a 250 code indicating a successful greeting
                if (preg_match('/^250/', $response)) {
                    // Send the AUTH command with your SMTP credentials (username and password)
                    $response = readResponse($socket);
                    fputs($socket, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
                    $response = readResponse($socket);
            
                    if (preg_match('/^334/', $response)) {
                        // Send the base64-encoded username
                        fputs($socket, base64_encode($username) . "\r\n");
                        $response = readResponse($socket);
            
                        if (preg_match('/^334/', $response)) {
                            // Send the base64-encoded password
                            fputs($socket, base64_encode($password) . "\r\n");
                            $response = readResponse($socket);
            
                            // Check if authentication was successful (usually 235 for success)
                            if (preg_match('/^235/', $response)) {
                                
                                // Send the sender's email address
                                fputs($socket, "MAIL FROM:<$username>\r\n");
                                $response = readResponse($socket);
                                
                                // Now you can send the RCPT TO command
                                fputs($socket, "RCPT TO:<$recipientEmail>\r\n");
                                $response = readResponse($socket);
                                
                                // Send VRFY command
                                fputs($socket, "VRFY $recipientEmail\r\n");
                                $response = readResponse($socket);
                                
                                // Check the response
                                if (preg_match('/^250/', $response)) {
                                    echo "The email address '$recipientEmail' exists on the server.\r\n";
                                } else {
                                    echo "The email address '$recipientEmail' does not exist or the server doesn't support VRFY.\r\n";
                                }

                                
                                // Close the connection
                                fputs($socket, "QUIT\r\n");
                                $response = readResponse($socket);
                                
                                
                            } else {
                                echo "SMTP authentication failed.\r\n";
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "Failed to send the password.\r\n";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "Failed to send the username.\r\n";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Failed to greet the SMTP server.\r\n";
                }
            
                // Close the socket connection when done
                fclose($socket);
            }
```

Response Screenshot on Above Code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuDEw.png)

I want to check email address is valid/invalid using PHP Socket SMTP Handshake

Comment: You're not saying it, but are you getting the message: _"The email address ...... does not exist or the server doesn't support VRFY."_? Or something else?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware check screenshot of the response: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuDEw.png

Comment: I see it. And you're sure that the server you connect to supports VRFY? Many SMTP servers do not support VRFY.

Comment: Most servers are probably set to _not_ support this - because that would be an easy way for _spammers_ to verify, which of the email addresses in their databases actually (still) exist.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Agree using VRFY is not a good option. I added a response check on RCPT TO: in this way i can check email is valid or not valid. Updating it on my code

Comment: @CBroe thank you for your response.  I agree with you comment. I've added answer to check the email valid/invalid and that code is working for me now. I hope it will cover all checks

Comment: OK. I can't really upvote your question and answer because of how you have structured your code. Way to many nested if's and no use of functions. This is [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). It's not difficult to rewrite. You have a condition and an error message, try to keep them together, and don't nest more than 1 or 2 levels deep.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yeah you're right I'll change it to. Actually I was just trying to run it. But still it's not authentic way. it's accepting all emails on RCPT TO response. It should show error If email address not exists. I don't know how millionverifier and other tools are working.

Comment: They probably use a very big database, all kinds of tricks, and perhaps even just try to send an email if all else fails. It's what they specialize in. We, mere mortals, shouldn't try to emulate that. I only check the bit after the ampersand before sending an email. I do this by using [checkdnsrr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr) on the MX and A records. You might need to use [idn_to_ascii()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-ascii) for domains containing non-ascii characters. However, I do use a mailing server that tells me if an email couldn't be delivered.

Comment: Agree.. I'm closing it because we can't use VRFY for all emails. because it's restricted by the recipient server. Thanks @KIKOSoftware